# How to use IDEA to auto complete YAML configurations

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml

I am currently working on spring boot and exploring the spring configurations for spring cloud using YAML. I always copy and paste the whole configuration from some source to my project, is there a way that IDEA auto-completes or shows suggestions while writing the spring cloud configurations. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [spring assistant](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10229-spring-assistant) plugin